# Use Python and BOTO3 to list AWS IP and devices

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm trying to use Python and BOTO3 to list out the IPs of all devices in AWS (ELBs, EC2 etc)

I've been able to pull the whole inventory but How can I assume a role and list out only the IP and device across all of my linked AWS accounts ?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but hope it's helpful. You should actually use `network_interfaces` to get IP addresses across all services. I run a similar report, using a collection of named profiles. Something like this:

```
for profile in self.profiles:
    print(f'Analyzing {profile}...')
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile)
    ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
    for eni in ec2.network_interfaces.all():
        attachment_info = 'No attachment'
        if eni.attachment:
            if 'InstanceId' in eni.attachment:
                attachment_info = eni.attachment['InstanceId']
            else:
                attachment_info = eni.attachment['InstanceOwnerId']

        row = (
            profile,
            eni.private_ip_address,
            eni.subnet_id,
            eni.subnet.cidr_block,
            attachment_info,
        )
        print(row)
```

Regarding the role across accounts, as you can see in the code, boto3 will honor the named profiles in the `~/.aws/config`. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html

However, you can also assume the roles directly in your code, via code like this:

```
sts = boto3.client('sts')
creds = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn=f'arn:aws:iam::{acct_id}:role/{role_name}',
    RoleSessionName='...'
)
auth = {
    'aws_access_key_id': creds['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    'aws_secret_access_key': creds['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    'aws_session_token': creds['Credentials']['SessionToken'],
}
session = boto3.Session(**auth)
ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
```

This may be preferable if, for example, you also need to loop over multiple regions.

Answer (score 0):

For EC2, it's easy to collect private/public ip addresses like following:

[EC2 — Boto 3 Docs 1.7.30 documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html)

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource(service_name='ec2',
                     region_name='xxx',
                     aws_access_key_id='xxx',
                     aws_secret_access_key='xxx')

for i in ec2.instances.all():
    print(i.private_ip_address)
    print(i.public_ip_address)
```

But, you need to use the iam key for EC2.

Comment: Is there a way to assume a role and do this across accounts?

Comment: @user9877726 You mean there are two another AWS accounts, and the account A collects information about ip addresses related with the account B ?

Comment: Yes,  There are multiple accounts tied together.  I'd like to assume a role  so that it can scan all accounts.